# C++ Dynamic Ragged Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have been trying to figure out this assignment for hours and can't grasp it yet. I'm trying to read in names from a txt document, which is working, and I need to store them in an char pointer array. Once the number of names is as big as the array size, I need to use REALLOCATION to make the array bigger (I can't use vector library).

I'm struggling with changing the name array size to make it bigger and deleting the old array from memory (it just crashes when I write delete [] names;).

Here is my currently broken code:

```
int numNames = 2;
    char * names[numNames] = {};
    ifstream namesFile("names.txt");

    //get names from user, put names in ragged array
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numNames) {
        if (namesFile.good() && !namesFile.eof()) {
            //add name to ragged array
            names[i] = new char[257];
            namesFile >> setw(256) >> names[i];
            i++;

            if (i == numNames) {
                //need a bigger array
                numNames *= 2;

                char * temp[20] = {};
                for (int j = 0; j < numNames / 2; j++) {
                    temp[j] = names[j];
                }
                delete [] names;
                names = temp;
            }
        }
        else {
            //end of file or corrupt file
            break;
        }
    }
    namesFile.close();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must only call `delete[]` on what you received from `new[]`. You didn't get `names` form `new[]` (it's not even a pointer!), but rather `names[i]`.

Comment: Also, note that VLAs (aka arrays of length determined at runtime) don't exist in C++. Your compiler seems to support them, but their use is not portable.

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: Please use `std::vector<std::string>` and drop these shenanigans with `new char[]`, `delete [] whatever;`, etc.  *I can't use vector library* -- Create your own simple vector class.

Comment: *I have been trying to figure out this assignment for hours and can't grasp it yet.* -- It was not meant for you as a beginner to figure out or grasp.  No new programmer in C++ will figure this out or get this to work properly and without bugs *without* tons of help from an experienced C++ programmer.  Unless you get the answer handed to you, there is no way to properly address code or assignments like this.

Comment: And the twist is that the experienced programmer, who could make this work, would likely not use such code but `std::vector<std::string>>`. A YAIT is a person who believes that arrays and pointers are basic things and standard containers are advanced. Experienced programmers know that it is the other way round.

Comment: I know, I know. I guess my professor wants us to know how they actually work before using vectors.

Comment: @Jared -- I see absolutely no benefit in writing this code to learn dynamic allocation in C++.  It basically is spaghetti logic trying to figure out when and where to allocate and deallocate memory -- you learn nothing from it.  It is not encapsulated and hard to maintain and follow.  What would make more sense would be an assignment where you're creating your own string or vector *class*, where pointer usage is encapsulated.

Answer (score -1):

The following statement does not do any dynamic allocation. It just declares an array of `pointers to char (char*)` on a stack of size `numNames`. So, it is not dynamic by any means:

```
 char * names[numNames] = {};
```

As such, you cannot change its size.

Instead you need to create a **pointer** to the array like the following:

```
char **names = new (char*)[numNames];
```

Same story for your `temp` down the road. Now you are free to delete/new and to assign pointers as well: `names = temp`.

Now, you need to read your char data from a file line by line and put it in the 'names' array. When you read a string, you can allocate space for it in the array member, i.e.

```
names[i] = new char [strlen(inputString) + 1]; // you need '+1' for termination char
```

and you can copy data from  your string after allocation, i.e.

```
 strcpy(name[i], inputString); // this is a standard 'c' string copy
```

you can also use `std::copy` or a for loop do do a copy or whatever. Another method is to use a standard 'c' `malloc` function to do allocation:

```
  name[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(inputString) + 1);
```

The difference is that when you would need to free memory, you would use `delete[] name[i]` in the first case and `free(name[i])` in the second. Though it looks like you do not need to free the memory in your task.

Now you just have to figure out how to read from the file.

Comment: Tried this but could only get it to add one name. Pointers to pointers also confuse me but I guess I must use them in this situation

Comment: no one prevents you from using `std::string` right? So, as alternative to above i suggest that you use `std::string *names = new std::string[numNames]`. Would this be more clear?

Comment: Nope :( can't use string. Only char arrays

Comment: i added more info to the answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring it out by myself. Used pointers to pointers like you wrote.